# Plotting columns in a matrix next to eachother

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a matrix(n,m) that for each m contains a trace that i want to plot.

I want to have the y axis as (1:m) where trace nr 1 is plotted at y=1, trace nr.2 at y=2 and so on. I am having trouble redefining the axis.
 Is there any way this can be done?
The values in each trace/column has approx. the same range.

Comment: Like `y = 1:m; plot( A(1,:), y )`, that doesn't seem right, can you help me understand?

Comment: If i just plot the data (plot(matrix)) it looks like this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/824/lhwo.jpg/, I want each of the colored lines to represent y=1,2,3... so I get a graph that looks sort of like this one (without the black) http://www.sjvgeology.org/oil/seismic_wiggles.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 1: You could add a constant to each column to plot it at different magnitude values;

```
plot(bsxfun(@plus,matrix,range(matrix(:)).*(1:size(matrix,2))));
```

Answer 2: You could use subplots:

```
for v=1:size(matrix,2)
    subplot(size(matrix,2),1,v); plot(matrix(:,v));
end
```

(Note: I may have columns and rows mixed up in my indexing, I **still** can't remember that sometimes...)